# How can I send an audio streaming from my PC to an Internet web page

Tags: wine, alsa, streaming

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS and I want to send the audio from my PC's audio software player (a Wine app, specifically), using ALSA audio, to an Internet web page (which has a link to some audio player, maybe Real Time, I guess).

How can I do it?

Can I do it? ???

Greetings & Blessings from Chile

Juan

Comment: What wine app are you trying to stream from?

Comment: It is called "ZaraRadio" or  "ZaraStudio" (different names but the same product).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [Icecast server](http://icecast.org) and point to the stream from your website using a "HTML5" `<audio>` element.

As Wine apps get channelled through the Linux sound system layers, you should be able to pick up the sound with a source client like IceS2. Make sure to select the correct recording input using mixer/control software, else you'll only stream silence.

Comment: I downloaded and installed "IceCast2" so... it is supposed in my PC... But I don't know where and I don't know how to use it!!!

Comment: It's called Icecast, no CamelCase. Also you need to make sure it's enabled in `/etc/default/icecast2`. It will respond to 'http://localhost:8000'. Then you also need to make sure that the server is reachable from the internet, so running that at home might not be ideal. For IceS there are example configuration files in `/usr/share/ices2/examples/` - You'll probably want to copy and use `ices-alsa.xml` as a template.

Comment: I saw the "/etc/default/icecast2" configuration file and it is enable (ENABLE=true). I don't have any "/usr/share/ices2" directory.

Comment: When I used, into a Terminal, the order: "icecast2 -c /etc/default/icecast2" I got the following mistake: "/etc/default/icecast2:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
# Defaults for icecast2 initscript
^
FATAL: error parsing config file (/etc/default/icecast2)
XML config parsing error
What's wrong here? ???